# How to obtain all subclasses of a given sealed class?

Tags: kotlin

Recently we upgraded one of our enum class to sealed class **with objects as sub-classes** so we can make another tier of abstraction to simplify code. However we can no longer get all possible subclasses through `Enum.values()` function, which is bad because we heavily rely on that functionality. Is there a way to retrieve such information with reflection or any other tool?

PS: Adding them to a array manually is *unacceptable*. There are currently 45 of them, and there are plans to add more.

---

This is how our sealed class looks like:

```
sealed class State

object StateA: State()
object StateB: State()
object StateC: State()
....// 42 more
```

If there is an values collection, it will be in this shape:

```
val VALUES = setOf(StateA, StateB, StateC, StateC, StateD, StateE,
    StateF, StateG, StateH, StateI, StateJ, StateK, StateL, ......
```

Naturally no one wants to maintain such a monster.

Comment: AFAIK adding them manually to an array is actually the only *acceptable* way to proceed here. You have no way to know all possible subclasses for a given class. This is a limitation of how the JVM actually works. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: [Related](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/KT-14657)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Can you post some code?

Comment: @m0skit0 There are actually [implementation](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) that do this, however it seems too heavy just for this situation.

Comment: @D3xter *obtain all subclasses of a given sealed class*, as said in title, and usage is *as replacement of Enum.values*. There *are* some questions that can be understood without code, and this is one of them. I added some code anyway, if you are really concerned about that.

Comment: @glee8e I'm not asking about code that you've tried to achieve your goal, but rather what you are trying to achieve with this code in a bigger picture. It seems to me, that you are trying to use sealed classes in a special way. For comparison, ADTs in most functional languages are not enumerable

Comment: @D3xter Well, we are using sealed classes as *enum types that can have direct super class other than Enum*. We just need a enum (complex one though) and we are not using it as ADT. As you can see, it's State.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

In Kotlin 1.3+ you can use [`sealedSubclasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html).

In prior versions, if you nest the subclasses in your base class then you can use [`nestedClasses`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/nested-classes.html):

```
Base::class.nestedClasses
```

If you nest other classes within your base class then you'll need to add filtering. e.g.:

```
Base::class.nestedClasses.filter { it.isFinal && it.isSubclassOf(Base::class) }
```

Note that this gives you the subclasses and not the instances of those subclasses (unlike `Enum.values()`).

---

With your particular example, if all of your nested classes in `State` are your `object` states then you can use the following to get all of the instances (like `Enum.values()`):

```
State::class.nestedClasses.map { it.objectInstance as State }
```

---

And if you want to get really fancy you can even extend `Enum<E: Enum<E>>` and create your own class hierarchy from it to your concrete objects using [reflection](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html). e.g.:

```
sealed class State(name: String, ordinal: Int) : Enum<State>(name, ordinal) {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic private val map = State::class.nestedClasses
                .filter { klass -> klass.isSubclassOf(State::class) }
                .map { klass -> klass.objectInstance }
                .filterIsInstance<State>()
                .associateBy { value -> value.name }

        @JvmStatic fun valueOf(value: String) = requireNotNull(map[value]) {
            "No enum constant ${State::class.java.name}.$value"
        }

        @JvmStatic fun values() = map.values.toTypedArray()
    }

    abstract class VanillaState(name: String, ordinal: Int) : State(name, ordinal)
    abstract class ChocolateState(name: String, ordinal: Int) : State(name, ordinal)

    object StateA : VanillaState("StateA", 0)
    object StateB : VanillaState("StateB", 1)
    object StateC : ChocolateState("StateC", 2)
}
```

This makes it so that you can call the following just like with any other `Enum`:

```
State.valueOf("StateB")
State.values()
enumValueOf<State>("StateC")
enumValues<State>()
```

---

**UPDATE**

Extending `Enum` directly is no longer supported in Kotlin. See 
[Disallow to explicitly extend Enum class : KT-7773](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-7773).

Comment: All right before KT-14657(thanks @HTNW) is resolved we should take this. And about the instance, well, we managed to find that `KClass` got an `objectInstance` property.

Comment: @glee8e Great. I'm glad it helped. I've updated my answer based on your updated question and your comment.

Comment: for those who like me cannot figure out immedaately where `isSubclassOf` coming from - it's kotlin reflect api. add `compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.1.4-3"` to your build.gradle dependencies

Comment: Thanks @Defuera I've added clarification that the enum-like solution requires reflection. Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting `Class Enum cannot be extended directly.`. Is this solution still supported?

Comment: @HendraAnggrian, apparently this is no longer possible as of Kotlin 1.1.4. :-(

Comment: @mfulton26 thanks for clarifying. Such a shame though, it's such a neat trick.

Comment: Base::class.nestedClasses method seems to break with java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError on android proguard obfuscated builds.

Comment: @southerton Sounds like you may have found a bug. I suggest looking to see if it already exists in JetBrains YouTrack and if not then creating a new issue there: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT?q=nestedClasses

Comment: Too bad `sealedSubclasses` is only supported on Kotlin/JVM as of 1.6.

Answer (score 9):

Full example:

```
sealed class State{
    companion object {
        fun find(state: State) =
            State::class.sealedSubclasses
                    .map { it.objectInstance as State}
                    .firstOrNull { it == state }
                    .let {
                        when (it) {
                            null -> UNKNOWN
                            else -> it
                        }
                    }
    }
    object StateA: State()
    object StateB: State()
    object StateC: State()
    object UNKNOWN: State()

}
```

Answer (score 8):

With Kotlin 1.3+ you can use reflection to list all sealed sub-classes without having to use nested classes: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/-k-class/sealed-subclasses.html

I asked for some feature to achieve the same without reflection: https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/list-of-sealed-class-objects/10087

Comment: This feature is useful but it's important for anyone considering using this to note that it can be very slow, because it uses reflection.

Answer (score 5):

A wise choice is using [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) in kotlin. and then write some providers to get a common class, enum, object or data class instance. for example:

```
val provides = ServiceLoader.load(YourSealedClassProvider.class).iterator();

val subInstances =  providers.flatMap{it.get()};

fun YourSealedClassProvider.get():List<SealedClass>{/*todo*/};
```

the hierarchy as below:

```
                Provider                    SealedClass
                   ^                             ^
                   |                             |
            --------------                --------------
            |            |                |            |
        EnumProvider ObjectProvider    ObjectClass  EnumClass
            |            |-------------------^          ^
            |                    <uses>                 |
            |-------------------------------------------|
                                 <uses>
```

---

Another option, is more complicated, but it can meet your needs since sealed classes in the same package. let me tell you how to archive in this way:

1. get the URL of your sealed class, e.g: `ClassLoader.getResource("com/xxx/app/YourSealedClass.class")`
2. scan all jar entry/directory files in parent of sealed class URL, e.g: `jar://**/com/xxx/app` or `file://**/com/xxx/app`, and then find out all the `"com/xxx/app/*.class"` files/entries.
3. load filtered classes by using `ClassLoader.loadClass(eachClassName)`
4. check the loaded class whether is a subclass of your sealed class
5. decide how to get the subclass instance, e.g: `Enum.values()`, `object.INSTANCE`.
6. return all of instances of the founded sealed classes

Comment: This still implies "adding them manually to an array" even if not literally :)

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, sir. indeed, the 1st approach is  manually. but it for the maintaining purpose. because you can split logic to pieces.

Comment: Yes but question states that "Adding them to a array manually is unacceptable".

Comment: @m0skit0 yes, sir. then I give him another complicated option.

Comment: Thanks for your complicated anwser. This is actually considered because it offers better flexiblity but we think this may have a great performance impact (*scanning the whole classpath sounds bad dude*). We'd rather make them all nested classes and use mfulton26's solution.

Comment: @glee8e Not at all. the hard thing is you must solve how to get all the instances of sealed class. if your sealed class subclass are `enum`s or `object`s there is no problem. but it has `class`es you must thing how to design your api.

Comment: They are `object` so it's okay. I have just updated my question to reflect that. After all, these sealed classes resulted from upgrading enums, so they must be singletons

Comment: @glee8e okay, the 2nd way is sufficient to you.

Answer (score 3):

If you want use it at child class try this.

```kotlin
open class BaseSealedClass(val value: String, val name: Int) {
    companion object {
        inline fun<reified T:BaseSealedClass> valueOf(value: String): T? {
            return T::class.nestedClasses
                .filter { clazz -> clazz.isSubclassOf(T::class) }
                .map { clazz -> clazz.objectInstance }
                .filterIsInstance<T>()
                .associateBy { it.value }[value]
        }

        inline fun<reified  T:BaseSealedClass> values():List<T> =
            T::class.nestedClasses
            .filter { clazz -> clazz.isSubclassOf(T::class) }
            .map { clazz -> clazz.objectInstance }
            .filterIsInstance<T>()
    }
}

@Stable
sealed class Theme(value: String, name: Int): BaseSealedClass(value, name) {
    object Auto: Theme(value = "auto", name = R.string.setting_general_theme_auto)
    object Light: Theme(value= "light", name = R.string.setting_general_theme_light)
    object Dark: Theme(value= "dark", name = R.string.setting_general_theme_dark)

    companion object {
        fun valueOf(value: String): Theme? = BaseSealedClass.valueOf(value)
        fun values():List<Theme> = BaseSealedClass.values()
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

For a solution without reflection this is a library that supports generating a list of types to sealed classes at compile time:
https://github.com/livefront/sealed-enum

The example in the docs

```kotlin
sealed class Alpha {
    object Beta : Alpha()
    object Gamma : Alpha()
    
    @GenSealedEnum
    companion object
}
```

will generate the following object:

```kotlin
object AlphaSealedEnum : SealedEnum<Alpha> {
    override val values: List<Alpha> = listOf(
        Alpha.Beta,
        Alpha.Gamma
    )

    override fun ordinalOf(obj: Alpha): Int = when (obj) {
        Alpha.Beta -> 0
        Alpha.Gamma -> 1
    }

    override fun nameOf(obj: AlphaSealedEnum): String = when (obj) {
        Alpha.Beta -> "Alpha_Beta"
        Alpha.Gamma -> "Alpha_Gamma"
    }

    override fun valueOf(name: String): AlphaSealedEnum = when (name) {
        "Alpha_Beta" -> Alpha.Beta
        "Alpha_Gamma" -> Alpha.Gamma
        else -> throw IllegalArgumentException("""No sealed enum constant $name""")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
sealedValues<State>()
```

```
inline fun <reified T> sealedValues(): List<T> {
    return T::class.sealedSubclasses.mapNotNull { it.objectInstance as T }
}
```

Comment: Would you mind knowing what about kotlin-multiplatform, since `sealedSubclasses` is unavailable?

Comment: I haven't tried KMP yet but sealedSubclasses comes with package kotlin.reflect
dependency:
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.8.10"

Answer (score 0):

The short version is

```
State::class.sealedSubclasses.mapNotNull { it.objectInstance }
```