# Kotlin Enum to Basic Type mapping

Tags: android, kotlin, enums, retrofit2

I have a login API, which accepts that a field, `type` is either "email" or "phone".

I'd like to make them Enums

```
enum class LoginBodyType (val value: String) {
    EMAIL("email"), PHONE ("phone")
}
```

I have a data class similar to follows

```
class LoginBody (val type: LoginBodyType) {
    var phone: String = ""
    var email: String = ""
    var password: String = ""
}
```

so that when I call the login function, it will be something like this

```
val body = LoginBody(LoginBodyType.EMAIL)
body.email = username
body.password = password
```

where the type will be fixed to one of the enums, but it would submit to the server as a type String.

One option is to do `body = LoginBody(LoginBodyType.EMAIL.value)` and `class LoginBody (val type: String)` but it feels like there's a more elegant solution. I'm using Retrofit 2 if that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
enum class LoginBodyType {
  EMAIL, 
  PHONE;
  override fun toString(): String = name.toLowerCase()
}

val body = LoginBody(LoginBodyType.EMAIL)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is better, but it still needs an explicit .toString() call instead of .value() in my situation.

Comment: No it wouldn't it is smart enough to cast it automatically try it.

LoginBody(LoginBodyType.EMAIL)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to play around with `sealed class`. So something like:

```kotlin
enum class LoginBodyType {
    EMAIL, 
    PHONE
}
sealed class LoginBody {
    data class Email(val email: String, val password: String)
    data class Phone(val phone: String)
}

val body = when(type) {
    LoginBodyType.EMAIL -> LoginBody.Email(email, pass)
    LoginBodyType.PHONE -> LoginBody.Phone(phone)
}
```

Alternatively check [How to obtain all subclasses of a given sealed class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784328/how-to-obtain-all-subclasses-of-a-given-sealed-class)